# Moving / Migrating image files from another site into an existing Drupal 7 site

Tags: 7, media, migrations, files

I'm currently doing a data migration from one Drupal 7 site to another Drupal 7 site. So far I exported the data from the old site into a CSV file and then have it get imported into the new site by looping through each row of each result and doing a $node object and then node_save.

The problem now is how do import/copy the images over? I have the url path from the old site.Do I use file_unmanaged_copy() function to get them into the system? But from the docs, it says I can only use public:// and I'm not sure if http urls to the images would work. Or is there another function I need to use for this purpose?

Comment: I recommend the [migrate_d2d][1] module for this job. It supports copying images if they are in fields.


  [1]: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [Feed Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import)  I am using it to import content from Joomla and WP sites into new Drupal sites with Drupal to Drupal export import should be a lot easy.
My process is as follows:

1. Create desired content types with all matching fields on the new
   site.
2. Create Import profile for this content type go to mystie/import to
   download csv template
3. Export content from the old site with path to images so to have
   matching content with image
4. Upload images to new web site and change paths in csv file
5. Import and create or update content.